# SEO impact of default language duplication vs redirects

Tags: seo, redirects, duplicate-content, internationalization, language

On our public gatsby website we have two languages: `nl` and `en`.
Our default language is `en`, so we have `/...`, `/en/...` and `/nl/...`.

So for one piece of content we have the following links:

- https://www.azumuta.com/how-it-works/work-instructions/
- https://www.azumuta.com/nl/how-it-works/work-instructions/
- https://www.azumuta.com/en/how-it-works/work-instructions/

Now, two of those are identical and all my SEO tools (like Ubersuggest, Hubspot, etc) are complaining about the duplicate title tags & content.

How should this be solved properly? Can we just redirect the `/...` pages to the `/en/...` without further SEO impact? And what's the best way to do redirects in Gatsby?

Comment: maybe this link can help you: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/consolidate-duplicate-urls

Comment: aha, thanks for the resource, seems like the gatsby gatsby-plugin-client-side-redirect module uses a 301 redirect, so that should probably do the trick!

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of redirects (Saw your comment), if you don't set `hreflang` annotations and canonicalize pages Google will likely consider them duplicates.

Via document `<head>`

```html
<head>
 <title>Example.com</title>
  <link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-gb" href="http://en-gb.example.com/page.html" />
  <link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-us" href="http://en-us.example.com/page.html" />
  <link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://en.example.com/page.html" />
  <link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="http://de.example.com/page.html" />
 <link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="http://www.example.com/" />
</head>
```

Via headers

```
Link: <http://example.com/file.pdf>; rel="alternate"; hreflang="en",
      <http://de-ch.example.com/file.pdf>; rel="alternate"; hreflang="de-ch",
      <http://de.example.com/file.pdf>; rel="alternate"; hreflang="de"
```

Via `sitemap.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
  xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.example.com/english/page.html</loc>
    <xhtml:link
               rel="alternate"
               hreflang="de"
               href="http://www.example.com/deutsch/page.html"/>
    <xhtml:link
               rel="alternate"
               hreflang="de-ch"
               href="http://www.example.com/schweiz-deutsch/page.html"/>
    <xhtml:link
               rel="alternate"
               hreflang="en"
               href="http://www.example.com/english/page.html"/>
  </url>
...etc
```

[This](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/136762/122139) answer I wrote recently has some useful resources.